# Loss function wrapping working in keras but not with tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss

I am building a network architecture where I need a layer output in the loss function. To achieve this I wrap my custom loss function to pass the layer as additional parameter. My loss function looks like:

```
def loss_wrapper(weights):
    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return ((y_true - y_pred) ** 2) / weights # dummy formula
```

Now using this loss in a simple architecture like:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(2, 1))
x = LSTM(5, return_sequences=True, activation="tanh")(inputs)
x1 = Dense(3, activation='relu')(x)
x2 = Dense(1, activation='relu')(x1)

loss = loss_wrapper(x1)
model = Model(inputs, x2)
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer="adam")
model.fit(dataset, steps_per_epoch=1000, epochs=10)
```

This code runs well using keras directly. When executing the same code using the tf.keras stuff it yields this error when executing the fit method:

```
TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.

_SymbolicException: Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found 
[<tf.Tensor 'dense_0/Identity:0' shape=(None, 2, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

Also annotating the wrapped loss function with tf.function does not work.

The Tensor tf.Tensor 'dense_0/Identity:0 is the tensor passed as param to the loss function. How must the loss function be changed to accept this input?

Are there any other workarounds in TF 2.1/2.2 instead of wrapping the loss function? I want to avoid a hacky approach concatenating the layer x1 with the output and further split it away from y_pred.

Comment: try to pass `x1` to `sample_weight` argument in model.fit() method. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. As I am passing the data to the fit method via a dataset API object, the param sample_weight is not allowed in this combination. As the docs say in this case it should be sampled as third parameter within the dataset object. But can I sample trainable layer weights into a dataset API object?